# Is there a way to make the Opentelemetry Java library trace into Spring EventListeners?

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry

We've got OpenTelemetry Java set up and it works great for most of our Spring app, but we heavily use event listeners using Spring's event publisher and the spans don't seem to continue into the event listeners. Is there a way to turn this on? What would I need to do to trace into the event listeners triggered by the main code flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @WithSpan and @SpanAttribute annotations from the OTEL libraries do this

```
@EventListener
@WithSpan
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void onEvent(@SpanAttribute("event") MyEvent event) {
    log.info(EVENT_RECEIVED_TEXT, event.getEventType());
    myService.doSomething(event.getId(), event.getStatus());
}
```

Comment: It would be better if this was done automatically (like with old libs). There isn't many scenario where you don't want to propagate this to Spring Event Listener.

Comment: Using @WithSpan didn't work for me. All it seems to be doing is creating new span but it doesn't use same trace id. It worked for me after creating context (using Context.current), storing it in MyEvent and passing it to Listener and then make that context current (using context.makeCurrent)